# Disable permisisons for a user through group policy

Tags: windows, active-directory

How can I create a group policy that is applied to a user object (not a computer) that will explicitly disable permissions such as Log on Locally and Log on through terminal services?

Is this something that can only be applied to computer objects, or is there an equivalent way to apply the change to any affected user when they try to use the account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The security setting is configured for computer objects. A user will be subjected to it. The user does not need to process the policy because the computer will be doing the enforcing.

So if you know which computers you dont want the user to be able to logon to, you can either

1. use group policies to enforce a list of users/groups that are allowed to logon (which will obviously not include the user in question) or
2. explicitly deny logon locally

Set "Deny logon locally" and "Deny logon through Remote Desktop Services" in Group Policy as follows:

**Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment**

On Windows Server 2003 and earlier, "Remote Desktop Services" is called "Terminal Services."